# Chrome/Safari basic testing: CSS, Javascript, Images not working when using IP address instead of localhost as it's looking for files in "https"

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, https

I have a basic nodes project running on my Mac using Express and EJS for views.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

The index.ejs links to the css, js and image files. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

This works fine on my Mac using localhost. But when I try using the IP address of my local Mac:

`http://192.168.12.112:8080/`

It only shows the HTML without any CSS/JS/images. In the developer tools, there are errors:

```
GET https://192.168.12.112:8080/style.css net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
GET https://192.168.12.112:8080/script.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
GET https://192.168.12.112:8080/face.jpeg net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

It seems like despite this being a local project, for the linked files, it's trying to evaluate using https (which of course doesn't work as I don't have SSL setup yet).

Why's this happening? I have tried using Chrome, Safari, Firefox and even my iPhone with same issue.

I don't want to setup SSL as this is just a local project within my own wifi.

Comment: There's clearly an SSL certificate set up for localhost and it appears requests for static files are being redirected to `https`. You don't show enough here, especially of your `app` script, for us to help you disable it.